# Workaround: RichTextBox shifts font dimension at small intervals

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I'm using RichTextBox in my project and I've noticed that it shifts it's font dimension at small intervals. For instance:

```
rtb1.Font = new Font("Arial", 1.869f*254.0f / 72.0f, FontStyle.Regular); // 5,3pt
rtb1.AppendText("lorem ipsum bla bla bla\n");

rtb2.Font = new Font("Arial", 1.834f*254.0f / 72.0f, FontStyle.Regular); // 5,2pt
rtb2.AppendText("lorem ipsum bla bla bla\n");
```

This code gives visually identical writings. Is there any workaround, to make RichTextBox actually shift the font dimension in continuity, without intervals?

upd: Playing around a bit I found out that the font holds the same dimension even for bigger intervals, for instance: 2.01f and 1.81 gives the same font size.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: `1.869 * 254 / 72` and `1.834 * 254 / 72` give `6.59` and `6.47` points, respectively, which means a difference of `0.12pt`, or `0.16px` at 96 DPI. Are you expecting a `0.16px` difference to be visible?

Comment: the value is already in mm, so 1.869mm corresponds to 5.3pt and 1.834 to 5.2pt

Comment: Your formula is flawed then: to get inches from millimeters you have to divide by `25.4`, not multiply by `254`. Then, to get points from inches, you have to multiply by `72`, not divide. In addition, my first point still stands: a `0.10pt` difference means `0.13px` at 96 DPI, which will probably not be visible even with subpixel rendering (if the font rasterizer supports it in the first place).

Comment: it isn't about the formula - formula is ok for my application. it's all about RTB making font dimension discrete from continuous. anyway I was able to create a workaround in my project. thanks for your time :)